# Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds

Tags: r

[SolutionPact] -> System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

```
SolutionPact <- SolutionPact %>%
  mutate(IOFutureForecast = coalesce(IOFutureForecast, 0),
         WEnzaMinQtyPerc = coalesce(WEnzaMinQtyPerc, 0),
         IOEffectiveLeadTime = coalesce(IOEffectiveLeadTime, 0),
         IOSuggestedSafetyStockFinal = coalesce(IOSuggestedSafetyStockFinal, 0))

TimeMapping <- subset(TimeMapping,select = c(1,2))
colnames(TimeMapping) <- c("Week","WeekKey")

SolutionPact <- merge(SolutionPact, TimeMapping,
                      by.x= "Time", by.y = "Week", all.x = TRUE )


SolutionPact0 <- SolutionPact %>% filter(IOEffectiveLeadTime <= 1)
SolutionPact0 <- SolutionPact0[order(SolutionPact0$Version,
                                     SolutionPact0$Location, 
                                     SolutionPact0$Item,
                                     SolutionPact0$WeekKey),]

SolutionPact0 <- SolutionPact0 %>% 
  group_by(Version,
           Location,
           Item) %>% 
  mutate(CumTotalx = 0) %>% 
  mutate(CumTotaly = IOFutureForecast) %>% 
  mutate(WEnzaTotalForecast = IOFutureForecast) %>% 
  mutate(WEnzaIOMinSafetyStockQty = (IOFutureForecast* WEnzaMinQtyPerc)) %>%
  mutate(TargetInventory = WEnzaIOMinSafetyStockQty)

#Ordering the data by Version,Location and Item
SolutionPact <- SolutionPact[order(SolutionPact$Version,
                                   SolutionPact$Location, 
                                   SolutionPact$Item,
                                   SolutionPact$WeekKey),]

SolutionPact <- SolutionPact %>% filter(IOEffectiveLeadTime > 1) %>% 
  group_by(Version,
           Location,
           Item) %>% 
  mutate(CumTotalx = ifelse(is.na(IOEffectiveLeadTime),IOEffectiveLeadTime,rollsumr(IOFutureForecast, 
                                                                                    k = round(IOEffectiveLeadTime,0), 
                                                                                    fill = NA))) %>% 
  mutate(CumTotaly = cumsum(IOFutureForecast)) %>%
  mutate(WEnzaTotalForecast = (ifelse(is.na(CumTotalx),
                                      CumTotaly,
                                      CumTotalx))) %>%
  mutate(WEnzaIOMinSafetyStockQty = (ifelse(is.na(CumTotalx),
                                            CumTotaly,
                                            CumTotalx))* WEnzaMinQtyPerc) %>%
  mutate(TargetInventory = WEnzaIOMinSafetyStockQty)

##new lines
TargetInventory <- union_all(SolutionPact,SolutionPact0)

TargetInventory$WEnzaIOMinSafetyStockQty[round(TargetInventory$IOFutureForecast,0)== 0] <- 0
TargetInventory$TargetInventory <- TargetInventory$WEnzaIOMinSafetyStockQty

TargetInventory = TargetInventory[c(2,3,4,1,12,13,14)]

#Rename the columns
names(TargetInventory)[1] ="[Version].[Version Name]"
names(TargetInventory)[2] ="[Location].[Location]"
names(TargetInventory)[3] ="[Item].[Item]"
names(TargetInventory)[4] ="[Time].[IO Planning Bucket]"
names(TargetInventory)[5] ="Measure.[IO Reversed Lead Time Demand (TP)]"
names(TargetInventory)[6] ="Measure.[W Enza IO Min Safety Stock Qty]"
names(TargetInventory)[7] ="Measure.[W Enza IO Target Inventory]"
```

Here is the code that gives the error. please help

A solution without error. Can you please help me solve this error."[SolutionPact] -> System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).